# Evaluating gamma functions.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-distributions, gamma-function

I am a bit lost on Gamma functions and would like to have the following evaluation from a textbook explained to me:

$\frac{\Gamma(k+1/2)}{\sqrt{\pi}} = \frac{\Gamma(k+\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})} = (k-\frac{1}{2})(k-\frac{3}{2})...\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2^k}(2k-1)!! = \frac{(2k)!}{4^k*k!}$

The first two equalities I understand, but when it comes to evaluating the factorials I'm not sure, since I assume that $\Gamma(1/2)$ is the irrational constant $sqrt(\pi)$ and can't really be neatly factored out.

Answer (score 3):

Recall the recursive property of the Gamma function:
$$\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$$

This means,

$$\Gamma(1/2+1)=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(1/2) \\ \Gamma(1/2+2)=\Gamma(1/2+1+1)=\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)\Gamma(1/2+1)=\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(1/2)$$
I'll do one more to make sure the pattern is clear.
$$\Gamma(1/2+3)=\Gamma(1/2+2+1)=\left(\frac{1}{2}+2\right)\Gamma(1/2+2)=\frac{5}{2}\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(1/2)$$
Clearly,
$$\Gamma(1/2+n)=\Gamma(1/2)\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2}$$

Therefore, and using the special value $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt \pi$,

$$\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\sqrt \pi}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2)}\Gamma(1/2)}\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2} \\ =\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot\left(\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)\right) \tag{1}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2^n}\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)\tag 2$$

The object $\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)$ is often written as $(2n-1)!!$ though personally I detest this notation and prefer $(2n-1)!_2$. Anyway, now comes the tricky part. We have to show that
$$\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$$

The easiest way to do this is to use a specific example that highlights how this works in general. So, I'll pick $n=4$ to demonstrate. See,
$$\prod_{k=1}^4(2k-1)=(2\cdot 1-1)\cdot(2\cdot 2-1)\cdot(2\cdot 3-1)\cdot (2\cdot 4-1)=1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$$
What we do now is add in the rest of the numbers on the top and bottom:
$$1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7=\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6 \cdot 7\cdot 8}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 8}=\frac{8!}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 8}$$
Now take out a two from each factor in the bottom:
$$\frac{8!}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 8}=\frac{8!}{(2\cdot 1)\cdot  (2\cdot 2)\cdot (2\cdot 3)\cdot (2\cdot 4)}$$
Now take all the twos to the outside:
$$\frac{8!}{(2\cdot 1)\cdot  (2\cdot 2)\cdot (2\cdot 3)\cdot (2\cdot 4)}=\frac{8!}{2^4\cdot (1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4)}=\frac{8!}{2^44!}=\frac{(2\cdot 4)!}{2^4\cdot 4!}$$
So we have shown
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\color{green}{4}}(2k-1)=\frac{(2\cdot \color{green}{4})!}{2^{\color{green}{4}}\color{green}{4}!}$$
And so in general
$$\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}\tag 3$$
Putting this back into $(2)$ we get
$$\frac{1}{2^n}\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)=\frac{(2n)!}{4^n n!}$$
And plugging this back into $(1)$ we get
$$\boxed{\frac{\Gamma(1/2+n)}{\Gamma(1/2)}=\frac{(2n)!}{4^n n!}}\tag 4$$
As desired.

---

By the way, this is just a reshuffled version of [Legendre's duplication formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html).
Substitute $m!=\Gamma(m+1)$:
$$\frac{\Gamma(1/2+n)}{\Gamma(1/2)}=\frac{\Gamma(2n+1)}{4^n\Gamma(n+1)}$$
Again use the recursive property of the Gamma function:
$$\frac{\Gamma(2n+1)}{4^n\Gamma(n+1)}=\frac{2n\cdot\Gamma(2n)}{2^{2n}n\cdot\Gamma(n)}=\frac{\Gamma(2n)}{2^{2n-1}\Gamma(n)}$$
Substituting $n\to z$ and combining the previous two equations we get
$$\frac{\Gamma(1/2+z)}{\Gamma(1/2)}=\frac{\Gamma(2z)}{2^{2z-1}\Gamma(z)}$$
Which is usually written as
$$\Gamma(2z)=\frac{2^{2z-1}\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1/2+z)}{\sqrt \pi}$$
As seen on the linked page.

Answer (score 2):

We have that:
$$\frac{\Gamma(x+½)}{\Gamma(x-½)}=x-½$$
for any $x>0$.

So you can write:
\begin{align}
\frac{\Gamma(k+½)}{\Gamma(½)}&=(k-½)\frac{\Gamma(k-½)}{\Gamma(½)}\\
&=\frac{2k-1}2\frac{\Gamma(k-½)}{\Gamma(½)}
\end{align}
which reorganizes as the form you have in your question.

Comment: It's not overly clear how this "reorganizes" to the form given in the question.